# Not showing anything on console (Angular)

Tags: angular, typescript

So I am new to Angular, I am writing some code only to show some data saved in a JSON file. I created localhost as my "server" and using this URL I want to show this data. The problem is that the code compiles, and on the console, there is no error but I am not getting anything shown. First of all, here is the **service file** I created:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Product } from 'src/app/orders/product/Interface/product.interface';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ProductsService {

  private apiURl= 'https://localhost:3000/products';
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }


  getProducts():Observable<Product[]> {
      return this.http.get<Product[]>(this.apiURl)
  }

}
```

As said before, I have no errors on the terminal. I tried writing just a simple *console.log()* to show me just some random text, but that even does not work.

Here it is the Component:

```
import { ProductsService } from './../../abraham/servies/products.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {tap} from 'rxjs/operators'



@Component({
  selector: 'app-product',
  templateUrl: './product.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product.component.css']
})
export class ProductComponent implements OnInit {



    constructor(private productSvc: ProductsService) {

    }



  ngOnInit() {
    this.productSvc.getProducts()
    .pipe(
      tap(res => console.log(res))

    )
    .subscribe();


  }

}
```

Any idea what would it be?
Thank you in advance

This is what I am getting on *Network*:

[The status is 200](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FOm12.png)

**json file**:
[db.json](https://github.com/domini-code/curso-angular-12/blob/dd827e71b6d4427f23027996deafc303ce2588a8/server/db.json)

I added this  `"serverAPI": "json-server --watch server/db.json --port 3000"`  in the *package.json* file so I could run it on the command prompt

Comment: Did you check with F12 DevTools --> Network, find the request of `https://localhost:3000/products`? Is it with status code 200 and returned any response?

Comment: Yes, I just modified the post with an image of it

Comment: Hi, how about the response data? Can you attach the response data in JSON to the question? Thanks.

Comment: Yes sure, I just did so

Comment: If you mov the console.log to subscribe(). Does it change the behaviour?

Comment: No it doesn't.  Still getting a blank console

Answer (score 0):

As your HTTP GET expect to receive the response value of `Product[]` type, while from your JSON is an `object` type with multiple properties.

Hence, you have to add `pipe` with `map` RxJS operator to retrieve and return `res['products']` for the `Product`  array.

> service.ts

```js
import { map } from 'rxjs';

getProducts(): Observable<Product[]> {
  return this.http
    .get<Product[]>(this.apiURl)
    .pipe(map((res: any) => res['products'] as Product[]));
}
```

[Sample Demo on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-uy3npq)

Comment: Okay, I see...I just tested it like but no changes at all :( . Still I'm not getting anything  returned